# BASH - Convert textfile containing binary numbers into a binary file

Tags: linux, bash, shell, scripting, hex

I have a long text file that looks something like this:

```
00000000
00001110
00010001
00010000
00001110
00000001
00010001
00001110
...and so on...
```

I'd like to take this data that is represented in ASCII and write it to a binary file. That is, i do NOT want to convert ASCII to binary, but rather take the actual 1s and 0s and put them in a binary file
The purpose of this is so that my EPROM programmer can read the file.
I've heard that ob and hexdump are useful in this case but I never really understood how they worked.

If it's to any help I also have the data in hex form:

```
00 0E 11 10 0E 01 11 0E
```

How do I do this using a shell script?

Comment: I think you need to use a language like perl or PHP. I can't think of a way to generate binary data in pure bash.

Answer (score 1):

Something like `perl -ne 'print pack "B*", $_' input` should get you most of the way there.

Comment: This is perfect! Thanks!  
    cat file.text | tr -d "\n" | perl -ne 'print pack "B*", $_' > file.bin